# Can we stop and start a JMS listener using Apache Camel?

Tags: jms, apache-camel

We have a requirement to stop a listener, and to start listener using camel. These listeners will be created using Apache camel routes. Is there a way to stop and start these listeners using camel?

Comment: It is a bit unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but Camel routes can be controlled (started, stopped and suspended) both programmatically and through JMX.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop "JMS listener created using Apache camel routes" (just another Camel route), using **Processor**:

```
.....
.process(new Processor() {
   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
       exchange.getContext().stopRoute("JMSListener");
   }
})
```

or you can use JMX, and stop the route or even stop the bundle.